# SSRS Format Time field without colon

Tags: time, reporting-services, format

I have an expression to return the time of execution on my report:

```
=Code.fnDocType(Fields,Parameters) & "  " & TRIM(Fields!SOP10100_SOPNUMBE.Value) & TRIM(FormatDateTime(Globals!ExecutionTime,4))
```

I wish to remove the column from the time display to display
:

```
1205 instead of 12:05
```

Expected results: 1205
Actual results: 12:05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
FormatDateTime(Globals!ExecutionTime,4)
```

with

```
Format(Globals!ExecutionTime, "HHmm")
```

or

```
Format(Globals!ExecutionTime, "hhmm")
```

"HHmm" gives 24 hour version "hhmm" gives 12 hour version.